# Were all symmetries of the universe spontaneously broken?

Tags: symmetry, symmetry-breaking

I can think of two distinct notions of symmetry. One in which I start with a system in state $\mathcal{S}_0$ and perform some transformation on it to get another system in state $\mathcal{S}_0'$. Now, I evolve these two systems for some time $t$, to get $\mathcal{S}_t$ and $\mathcal{S}_t'$ respectively. If undoing the transformation on $\mathcal{S}_t'$ gets us back to $\mathcal{S}_t$, I call this a symmetry. But there is one more, much stronger notion of symmetry, in which I start with $\mathcal{S}_0$ and I perform a transformation such that the transformation leaves the state invariant, so it evolves exactly the same way as the non-transformed state, i.e $\mathcal{S}_t' = \mathcal{S}_t$ for all time $t$.

When we talk of the symmetries of the universe, for example, when we say that the universe is Lorentz invariant, it's obviously in the first sense, I mean, the universe clearly looks different when you rotate it. However, for this to occur, we must start with a state that is not symmetric under the transformation. Otherwise, there is nothing to break the symmetry, and the state would remain symmetric under the transformation. This means that all the symmetries of the universe were spontaneously broken at some point. Is that correct?